# USCF player question

Tags: analysis, database, uscf

I was looking at the list of uscf players (as anyone can through WinTD) and two columns in a dataset, downloadable through the program, are titled RSUPP_NUM, R_PLR_TYP.

Does anyone have any idea what these columns mean? I see that these are short for Rating Supplement Number and Rating Player Type, but am unsure of why this is there.

Here's a screenshot of what the data looks like.

[image: USCF chess]

Here is all of the possible values in both of the columns.

For RSUPP_NUM:

[image]

For R_PLR_TYPE:

[image]

Does "E" mean experienced, and "P" mean provisional?

Does the 1-12 value mean it correspond to months? Does it mean the rating a person has corresponding to that month's value?

Comment: If P is provisional, then E would probably stand for Established, not Experienced.  (Although the idea would be the same.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be verified by looking at player information on http://uschess.org, RSUPP_YR and RSUPP_NUM are the year and month of the latest supplement with a rating for that player (which is in the R_LPB_RAT columns). If you looked up a sample player who has a P in R_PLR_TYP, it wouldn't be hard to confirm whether that means that the rating is provisional.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that it meant the most recent rating essentially.